# How can I Disable Disk Management using snap-in. After editing the compmgmt it dose not save

Tags: windows-7

I am able to edit the commgmt through MMC but when I try to save it did not save.
I want to disable Disk mgmt from compmgmt in windows 7 pro.

All this can be done easily in win Xp. Please let me know if any one of you can inplement the same in windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Open **gpedit.msc** from either **CMD** or **Run**

Follow the tree:

- User Configuration ->

  - Administrative Templates ->

    - Windows Components ->

      - Microsoft Management Console ->

        - Restricted/Permitted snap-ins

[image]

Select **Disk Management**

[image]

Select **Disabled** to remove any access to **Disk Management**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of Windows do more and more to protect their system files from malicious alteration, so your change might be being blocked by one of those traps.

This may be something that you can control using the Local Policy settings (Local Security Policy under Administrative Tools) and Group Policy (edited from your domain controller if using a Windows domain based network).

I couldn't tell you where in the tree to look for such a setting, but searching documents like [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25250) may be fruitful if such a setting exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove Disk Management from `compmgmt.msc`, you do *not* disable it – anyone can just run `mmc` and create their own consoles. There's also the command-line `diskpart`/`mountvol`, and finally direct disk access.

A more reliable solution is to remove Administrator rights from the user.